# Java Heap Space on two different computers

Tags: java, error-handling, heap-memory

I ran into the following problem:

The same Java program in Eclipse. On my computer (Macbook Air, 8GB Ram) I get the HeapSpaceError Java Heap Space.
The same Java program on a MacBook Pro, 8GB Ram I don't get the Error.

The initial Heap Space and the Max Heap Space is the same.

Any ideas why this error occurs?

Comment: Have you tried attaching an appropriate tool and looking at how much memory is actually used and what is using it?

Comment: Not yet, I just increase my Heap and then it works. I just found it pretty weird that the same program uses apparently a different about of Memory on two different machines...
I thought maybe it is a common thing or something.

I will try later to use a tool to determine the memory usage. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Are they running the same JVM (brand/flavor/version/etc)?  The JVM is responsible for performing GC, so the implementation of the JVM has a lot to do with how well the GC is implemented.  Also, could matter if one is configured to run as 32-bit vs. 64-bit.  Or if one was executed using the `-server` flag vs. `-client` flag, the former of which skips loading the AWT and Spring classes at start-up.  There are plenty of tools out there to analyze GC logs and such.  These may be of some use here.

Comment: @CodeChimp I was in the middle of writing essentially that and you got there first :).  64 bit JVMs will in general use more memory than 32 bit ones (all the pointers are twice as big for a start). I think you mean Swing not Spring though.

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks already for all these hints.

Comment: There are entire books written on the subject of JVM tuning.  It's a complicated and slippery topic, and usually depends highly on the application and the environment it runs in.  I once worked one an app that was getting OutOfMemoryErrors, but when we increased the heap they got worse, not better.  Ultimately, we solved it my making the total heap about 256mb smaller, but increasing Perm Gen by like 64mb.  What it came down to is this app, in particular, was exhausting the GC before it could free the memory, and adding more just meant the GC had more work when it actually did run.